# C: stucking with struct , reading data from file to struct using fscanf and pointer to a struct

Tags: c, file, pointers, struct, scanf

I am new here and new to C too :) 
Iam learning about struct and i getting trouble with this :

```
    Company **com_ptr;
int n,i=0;
FILE *fd;
fpos_t pos;
fd=fopen("C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\text.txt","r+");
if(fd==NULL){
    printf("That file not exits.\n");
}
else{
    fgetpos(fd,&pos);
    com_ptr=(Company**)malloc(sizeof(Company*)*15);
    for(i=0;i<15;i++) com_ptr[i]=malloc(sizeof(Company));
    i=0;
    while(!feof(fd)){
            fsetpos(fd,&pos);
                fscanf(fd,"%[A-Z a-z]",&com_ptr[i]->fName);         
            fscanf(fd,"%[A-Z a-z]",&com_ptr[i]->position);          
            fscanf(fd,"%[A-Z a-z 0-9]",&com_ptr[i]->depart);            
            fscanf(fd,"%[A-Z a-z 0-9]",&com_ptr[i]->office);            
            fscanf(fd,"%[0-9 /]",&com_ptr[i]->bDate);           
            fscanf(fd,"%[MALEFmalef]",&com_ptr[i]->sex);            
            fscanf(fd,"%[0-9 /]",&com_ptr[i]->sWorking);            
            fscanf(fd,"%ld",&com_ptr[i]->salary);[enter image description here][1]
            fgetpos(fd,&pos);
            i++;
    }
    printf("Input the person that you want to check : ");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("Full name : %s",com_ptr[i]->fName);
    printf("\nPosition  : %s",com_ptr[i]->position);
    printf("\nDepart    : %s",com_ptr[i]->depart);
    printf("\nOffice    : %s",com_ptr[i]->office);
    printf("\nDoB       : %s",com_ptr[i]->bDate);
    printf("\nSex       : %s",com_ptr[i]->sex);
    printf("\nStarting  : %s",com_ptr[i]->sWorking);
    printf("\nSalary    : %ld",com_ptr[i]->salary);
    free(com_ptr);
    fclose(fd); 
}
```

my idea is : i am trying to read data from a file. That file contains information about lots of employess.
The example of the file like this:
Andrew
Director
Block A
A4
02/10/1990
Male
01/01/2010
2500000

---

//Dear @xing this is the output of your code. Sorry for taking too long
John Terry

Director

President Block

1A

16/01/1990

Male

26/11/2010

Lionel Messi

Director

President Block

3A

26/01/1987

Male

10/01/2010

Comment: oh sorry for messy code :(

Comment: Not clear what trouble you are getting. Your `fscanf` looks like is taking a regex - never saw that.

Comment: when i use fscanf(fd,"%s",com_ptr[i]->fName) it just read the first work and skip other in the same line so that i think i will list all of the character that can appear in name :)

Comment: Where exactly does your trouble occurs? I don't think that `"r+w"` is a proper mode for opening files with `fopen`. If you want to read-only in the file use `"r"` or if you want to read and write use `r+`

Comment: Thanks Phil i have change it

Comment: I have add a pictures about the output of this code

Comment: oh i throught it will stop when it reach end-of-line

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You haven't told us what behaviour you are seeing and how this differs from what you are expecting. Also, the fact that you have spaces inside your %[] is probably making it include spaces in the match, which will make it match much more than you are expecting...

Comment: oh i think i getting trouble when reading data from file to stuct. in the text file each employees have 7 lines of information. i expect the program will read these information line by line until it reach eof. the bunch of printf commands at the end of this code i use to check that if the code run exactly or not. But when i run the program shown as the image == i guess i making mistake inside the while loop but i cannot find it